# Best way to sort by @onetomany collection size in spring boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="spot", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<SpotLikes> likes  = new HashSet<SpotLikes>();
```

So i have field like this. I want to sort by likes count. What is the best way?
When im using pagination it doesnt sort well. For example we have 5 posts and when i request sorting

> by likes descending

it show spots in order:
1,1,1,2,0 likes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are using a Set (which is inherently unsorted) rather than a List (which is inherently sorted).

Comment: I had list first and it didn't worked. I think order doesn't matter in this scenario. I wart to sort by collection size, and collection size is always the same independently from order.

Comment: What are you actually using to sort the response? Is there an @OrderBy somewhere?

Comment: Im using findAll(Pageable pageable) method from the Post repository.

Comment: There is no any @OrderBy, i didn't found the way like @OrderBy("count(id)") for example

Answer (score 0):

Even if you fetch the data sorted, you put it into a `Set` which does not guarantee order. You can use a `TreeSet` instead of `HashSet`.

Comment: TreeSet didn't helped. I think order doesn't matter in this scenario. I wart to sort by collection size, and collection size is always the same independently from order.